# Unable to add installed Glassfish 3.1 to Netbeans 7.0

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I recently migrated to Netbeans 7.0(with glassfish 3.1) from 6.9(with glassfish 3.0). After that glassfish server ran just for the first time and when  I restarted netbeans, since then,  it doesnt show glassfish in the servers list.

Now when I am trying to add my already installed server to netbeans, on pointing to installation location of server, it says `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1`(*my glassfish installation directory*) does not have a usable default domain.
Then on selecting : `Register Local Domain` it asks for:

```
Enter the path to a directory that will contain a new domain.
```

On selecting any directory, it says : `Unsupported domain at C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1; Admin-listener is disabled or no enabled http-listener`

How do I rectify this and add Glassfish support to my netbeans 7.0 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem and I managed to solve it this way:-

Just run NetBeans as Administrator & try again repeating your steps, everything will work!

I think that NetBeans doesn't have a right to create folders outside of it's own if you don't run it as an Administrator.

Comment: It might be nicer to choose a location which you have write access to, instead of starting Netbeans as Administrator (or to give yourself write access on the folder you want to use as domain)

Answer (score 1):

This issue also occurred for me in UNIX using GlassFish 4.1.1.

My fix involved gaining write privileges to my GlassFish folder (located for me in /usr/local/glassfish-4.1.1). This can be done by using the chmod command, which requires sudo access if not the owner.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but this time Netbeans 8 with Glassfish 4.x  win7, the way I solved it is below:
No need to run netbeans as administrator.
No need to dowload the Glassfish zip file, you'll dowload through netbeans IDE.

```
-create a dir where you'll place your glassfish installation files. In my case (win7) is:    
 C:\glassfish4
-Enter glassfish ide, go to Services / Servers / Add Server
-when Netbeans request your GlassFish location, browse the one we created above.
-select "Remote Domain"
-mark "I have read and accept licence agreement"
-press "Download" and select glasfish 4, ok.
```

this should start dowloading the Glasfish Server, just complete configurations steps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Java EE is not activated in the IDE. In the Services window, the Servers node is then empty. The node allows to add a new server, and in the process activates Java EE. Now when trying to register, the IDE discovers that it already has the selected server, refusing to register it twice. Just cancel and use the existing server in the refreshed Servers node.